# Giving alias to dataframe column name while selecting it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

It's common for me to write the following:

```
df = df1[['User', 'f1']].merge(df2[['User','f2']])
df.rename(columns={'f1':'feature 1', 'f2':'feature 2'}, inplace= True)
```

It is possible to do something as in SQL (using 'as' to give alias) like:

```
df = df1[['User', 'f1' as 'Feature 1']].merge(df2[['User','f2' as 'Feature 2']])
```

Comment: I don't think this is available in pandas there is a github issue [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11723) which doesn't seem active.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename these columns afte you are done merging like this:

```
df.rename(columns={"f1": "Feature 1", "f2": "Feature 2"}
```

Hope this helps!